# Can my outposts be attacked while I am not at them?

Tags: starfield

I've noticed occasionally enemies show up at your outposts, but the times it has happened to me, I was there and killed them pretty quickly. Most recently, I built an outpost on a fairly high leveled planet, and immediately saw a bunch of spacers show up, but between me, my follower, and local wildlife, they died before doing any damage.

I haven't noticed any attacks occurring while I have been away however. I haven't seen any notifications saying they were being attacked, nor have I noticed any damage to my outposts. Can my outposts be attacked while I am away, or are they just events that occur while you are there?

Comment: Do you have a crew member in your outpost to watch/guard the process of whatever you do there? I ask, because I think, enemies (NPC and creatures) only attack, if humans are present. Also a harsh environment seems not to "attack" an outpost (acid, corrosion).

Comment: @PeterCo i do have some crew members at one outpost. Its on Andrapon.

Comment: I guess they can be as you can build turrets

Comment: The text in game seems to indicate that it only happens when you're there, but isn't super clear. Additionally, so far, I've never had anyone attack when I wasn't there.

Answer (score 2):

Starfield has no static memory at outposts beyond resource extraction. No, your outposts won’t be attacked when you aren’t there. The existence of outpost defenses is purely decorative at this point.